# Apache redirect from root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I was just wondering how to perform a redirect from root in Apache.

I want to check if someone goes to the root url (eg. `example.com`) and redirect them to `example.com/h` automatically.

Can I do this in apache config, or in a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 5):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /h
</VirtualHost>
```

This will help you to redirect all your request from `example.com` to `example.com/h`

Comment: @w3d please give some more example on that . i am also here to learn and not to worry about downvote :)

Comment: A destination URL of `example.com/h` (ie. without a scheme) will result in an immediate server error (you won't be able to restart Apache). This needs to be either fully qualified eg. `http://example.com/h` or root-relative, eg. simply `/h`. However, since `RedirectPermanent` is "prefix" matching and you are redirecting to the _same server_, it will result in a redirect loop. ie. `/` to `/h` to `/hh` to `/hhh` etc. (because it also appends everything after the match). However, this can be easily fixed by using `RedirectMatch` instead. For example: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /h` would fix it. :)

Comment: Thanks Much :) will be answering to all apache related queries hereafter you are there to help me if i am wrong, happy to know you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `mod_rewrite` rule in Apache config or in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /h [L,R=302]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` after verifying this redirect rule. If you don't want the URL in the browser to change then use:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /h [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in either Apache config or .htaccess (per directory config files).

Using mod_rewrite in .htaccess, to redirect from the root to a specific URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /h [R,L]
```

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect.